# How to make an array of valid date

Tags: php, date

I need to make an array of valid dates with leap year, for example:

```
$year = 2012;

$month = 04;

$days = array('01', '02', '03', '04', '05' etc..)
```

how can i check every day of each month of each year and then push all that in an array, and then put that in a select tag

```
<select name="years">

</select>

<select name="months">

</select>

<select name="days">

</select>
```

some idea?

Comment: ps: i think that i need to use the built-in function checkdate() - but how to make an elegant loop to check all that?

Comment: any links will be appreciated

Comment: What's the MySQL connection to this question?

Comment: i am using a zend framework connection to mysql

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do this at client side using JavaScript ?

Comment: Populate the Month and Day list when user selects an year from the dropdown(using JavaScript). And when this data is submitted to the server, do a server side checking(using PHP) to check whether the submitted date(Year+Month+Day) is a valid date. Wouldn't that be better ?

Comment: xmmm this so this is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense. If you want to create select lists, all days (1-31) are valid since they are valid for some dates, so you always have to list them so the user can select them.

Because you don't have to enumerate all the valid dates, you only have to verify the sent data which is doable with [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php). You can put additional Javascript check to verify the date before sending the request.